# My function is returning list of empty object a

Tags: node.js

I have created a function to populate a list of objects but they are not being written.

```
if (stats.isDirectory()) {
        objlist=[];
        //do something here.. the path was correct
        fs.readdir(path, (err, files) => {
            objlist=[];
            for(file in files){
                //console.log(files[file])
                objlist[file]={};
                fs.stat(path + '\\' + files[file], function(err,stats){
                    if(err)
                        throw err;
                    if(stats.isDirectory()){
                        objlist[file]['file'] = 'folder'
                    }
                    if(stats.isFile()){
                        objlist[file]['file'] = 'file'
                    }
                    objlist[file]['name'] = files[file]
                    objlist[file]['size'] = stats.size
                    //console.log(objlist)
                    //console.log(stats)
                });
            }
        });
      console.log(objlist);
      return objlist;
    }
```

However the function returns an empty objlist; Can you please suggest what I am doing wrong

Comment: try using readdirsync. Also you should know that it's all async so return statement will not wait. See basics.

Comment: please notice that `readdir()` is async function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this code will be helphul. use `let file in files`

```
 objlist=[];
        //do something here.. the path was correct
        fs.readdir(path, (err, files) => {

            objlist=[]; 
            for(let file in files){
                objlist[file]={};
                fs.stat(path + '\\' + files[file], function(err,stats){
                    if(err)
                        throw err;
                    if(stats.isDirectory()){
                        objlist[file]['file'] = 'folder'
                    }
                    if(stats.isFile()){
                        objlist[file]['file'] = 'file'
                    }
                    objlist[file]['name'] = files[file]
                    objlist[file]['size'] = stats.size

                    if(file == files.length-1) {
                        console.log(objlist);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You must add the objects to the array with the method `push`, like this:

```
objlist=[];
for(file in files){
    obj = {};
    obj.file = file;
    //... do all stuff with obj
    objlist.push(obj);
}
```

Also your function is asynchronous inside the `fs.readdir`, so if you have to build and populate in the function or do an await to receive the result.

Otherwise you will call the function, it will be executed asynchronously, you will continue at the main function without the wait of the response of the `fs.readdir` and the array will continue empty because you async function may or may not have been executed.

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes in your code:-

1) You are using an array as an object

2) Since for loop is synchronous loop and you are trying asynchronous task inside it and hence either use synchronous version of fs or change your for loop as follows:-

```
for(file in files) {
    obj = {};
    obj[file]={};
    (function(f){
                fs.stat(path + '\\' + files[f], function(err,stats){
                    if(err)
                        throw err;
                    if(stats.isDirectory()){
                        obj[file]['file'] = 'folder'
                    }
                    if(stats.isFile()){
                        obj[file]['file'] = 'file'
                    }
                    obj[file]['name'] = files[file]
                    obj[file]['size'] = stats.size
                    objlist.push(obj)
                    //console.log(objlist)
                    //console.log(stats)

                });
            }
    }(file))
}
```